# Running two tmux sessions as systemd service

Tags: linux, tmux, systemd

I can successfully start/stop a service that creates a tmux session. The service is as following:
test1.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=First test service

[Service]
Type=forking
User=lancer
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s test1 -d
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux kill-session -t test1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`$ sudo systemctl start test1.service`
and
`$ sudo systemctl stop test1.service`

are both successful. Now I would like to have another tmux session that I can control from another service.
So I create this test2.service:

```
    [Unit]
    Description=Second test service
    
    [Service]
    Type=forking
    User=lancer
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s test2 -d
    ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux kill-session -t test2
    
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Problem**: Any of the two works alone. I can see the corresponding tmux session by:
`$ tmux ls`
If I start the other service, nothing happens. I only have the previous tmux session.
Can some one please help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Type=forking` is not the right type here. It makes systemd expect the `tmux` process (run from `ExecStart=`) to fork. But this `tmux` not always forks.

- If there is no tmux server, the `tmux` command will fork. The new `tmux` process will become a server, it will survive after the original `tmux` process exits. This is exactly what systemd expects from `Type=forking`. That's why any of the two services works alone.
- If there is already a tmux server, the `tmux` command will communicate with it to create a session; but it won't fork, there is no need to fork. The process will exit without leaving a forked process, still it will report success. My tests indicate that in such situation `ExecStop=` gets executed. In your case `ExecStop=` kills the newly created session right away. You don't notice the session is there briefly, you think nothing happens.

One way to deal with the issue is to create a "master" service that starts a tmux server *for sure*. For it `Type=forking` is right. You can start a dummy session from it or use [`start-server`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#start-server) (with `exit-empty off`) and let it run without any session.

Services that create actual sessions should use `Type=oneshot` with `RemainAfterExit=yes`, I think. They should want (`Wants=`) or require (`Requires=`) the "master" service. I'm not familiar enough with systemd to propose a detailed solution; I'm not even sure if the idea with a "master" service is the best.

Anyway, now you know why in certain circumstances allegedly nothing happens.

Comment: Using your idea and lots of experiments, now I have a solution. I put it down as a reference. Thank you!

Comment: @afar Good. I have already noticed and upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Kamil Maciorowski, I have a solution. Three steps:

1. Define a master service, **master.service**, as following:

```
[Unit]
Description=tmux master service

[Service]
Type=forking
User=lancer
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s master -d
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux kill-session -t master

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Define the first service,  **test1.service**, as following:

```
[Unit]
Description=tmux test 1 service
PartOf=master.service
After=master.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=lancer
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s test1 -d
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux kill-session -t test1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. Define the second service,  **test2.service**, as following:

```
[Unit]
Description=tmux test 2 service
PartOf=master.service
After=master.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=lancer
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s test2 -d
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux kill-session -t test2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Notes**:

1. @Kamil Maciorowski explains why `forking` and `oneshot` are used.
2. The master.service creates a  dummy tmux session called **master** that does nothing but hosts the other actual tmux sessions.
3. In the test1 and test2 services, `After` is to make sure at boot-up, the test1 and test2 services start after the master service.
4. In the test1 and test2 services, `PartOf` is to make sure that if the master stoped, the test1 and test2 services also stop. Without this, if master stops, test1 and test2 statuses show they are still active.

Comment: In the past I used to use `tmux start-server \; wait-for dummy` which does not need a session. Unfortunately at some point they broke wait-for completely, so the "dummy tmux session" is the only remaining option.